# Setting cookie using Kohana 3.1 helper class results in server error : 500

Tags: php, kohana, php-5.3, kohana-3

I am trying to make use of [Kohana helper "Cookie"](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/api/Cookie) class.
Doesn't seem to work, gives 500 error on calling.

`setcookie($name,$value)` works though.

What might be the reason??

Comment: Please provide some more information, such as what error message and how you are using the class. "500 error on calling" doesn't say anything really.

Comment: I meant -> when I try the page in browser, I do get "500 : internal server error", thats all... And no, the error page is not from Kohana, not that red bordered one...

Comment: Anyway, @The Pixel Developer showed me the way, thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only place where I could see that function failing is if you have failed to provide a [cookie salt](https://github.com/kohana/core/blob/3.1%2Fmaster/classes/kohana/cookie.php#L152). Make sure you set one and see if this fixes your error. In the bootstrap:

```
// Use a long and random value.
Cookie::$salt = ''
```

Comment: oops, no, I now realize, the blank '' doesn't work... We definitely need something in it!! Thanks... Accepted...

Comment: BTW, in case anyone is wondering, don't use the helper if you don't want to salt the cookie... Read more here : http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/7972/cookie-salt/p1